# Chart in ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, charts, asp.net-core-mvc

I have some chart, which show me progress of patient. I have a class patient

```
namespace PersonalArea.DAL.Models
{
    public class Result
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string PatientId { get; set; }

        public string GameName { get; set; }

        public string Time { get; set; }

        public int Score { get; set; }

        public int Level { get; set; }

        public DateTime FirstEnter { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateEnter { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateExit { get; set; }

        public string DifficultLevel { get; set; }

        public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Method on controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Results(string id)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            Patient patient = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id) as Patient;
            if (patient == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            ResultChartModel chartModel = new ResultChartModel
            {
                Surname = patient.Surname
            };
            List<Result> results = _context.Results.Where(x => x.PatientId == id).GroupBy(z => z.GameName).Select(x => x.LastOrDefault()).ToList();
            ViewBag.Test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);
            return View(chartModel);
        }
```

ViewModel for my class
    namespace PersonalArea.WebUI.ViewModels
    {
        public class ResultChartModel
        {
            public string Surname { get; set; }

```
        public List<Result> Results { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And result.cshtml

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 400px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         window.onload = function ()
        {
            var test = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ViewBag.test));
            var datapoints = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++)
            {
                datapoints.push({ y: test[i].Score, x: test[i].Score });
            }

            var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                theme: "theme2",
                animationEnabled: true,
                title: {
                    text: "Simple Column Chart in ASP.NET MVC"
                },
                subtitles: [
                    { text: "Try Resizing the Browser" }
                ],
                data: [
                {
                        type: "line", //change type to bar, line, area, pie, etc
                        dataPoints: datapoints

                }
                ]
            });
            chart.render();
        };
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Chart working, but he shows only last data. How can make, that chart show all data (all scores in the table)? How can I ignore `LastOrDefault` on a method of the controller?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, just select x=>x without last or default. Also probably will be good to mention, that your datetime values won't be shown in canvas js. Use for that either regular string or convert them to long value

Comment: Agree with Demon. Just use select x=>x.